# uidatepicker getting distorted, need help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, uidatepicker

In my app i am showing `UIDatePicker` and its getting distorted for some reason.
 Well the basic explanation for this to happen is that I am going from landscape mode to portrait mode to show a view that has my `UIDatePicker`. **I am not rotating this view. I am just showing this view from an another `view` which was in `landscape mode`. In fact I am not changing the rotation of this view at all.**

you can see in the pics below what exactly happening

here is the pic of IB.

[image]

and the pic of simulator.

[image]

PS: i also tried to create the picker from code and still the same result.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are the springs and struts setup for the UIPickerView? Check the size and position tab of the inspector.

Comment: @Mark i dont think you got the question so let me try to make it more clear.

Comment: What happens if you send [picker setNeedsLayout] in your viewDidLoad method? Just a guess, looks like the autoresizing causes some trouble here.

Comment: @JustSid nothing changed, the same thing happened.thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What NR4TR said is right. Since the previous view is in landscape, the picker is getting distorted. You can try saving the IB (containing the picker view) in landscape mode. I hope that will solve the problem.

Comment: thanks, the height of picker is reduced though but it is atleast in the centre of the screen. Thanks

Comment: That is because your IB content cannot fit in landscape mode as there is no room after you introduce the picker.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem.  When you load a view while already in Landscape orientation the UIPicker is not rendered correctly.  I spent several hours trying to find a workaround until I found a fix from [this page from Llamagraphics](http://www.llamagraphics.com/developer/UIDatePicker.html).  You add this code in viewDidLoad of the view controller that has the picker:

```
for (UIView* subview in myPicker.subviews) {
    subview.frame = myPicker.bounds;
}
```

Visit the [webpage](http://www.llamagraphics.com/developer/UIDatePicker.html) for more details.  Thank you Stuart!

Comment: Hey thats a nice very nice tip to show uidatepicker in landscape mode, thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

When datepicker comes from the view that have been in landscape mode it tries to adjust it's frame horizontally automatically and there is **no way to prevent it**. You have to rotate your view back to portrait and then reinitialize the picker explicitly after changing the orientation.